# las operaciones MIXCOLUMNS Y ADDROUNDKEY de AES pueden conmutar?

Tags: encriptación

Queria saber si las operaciones MIXCOLUMNS Y ADDROUNDKEY de AES pueden conmutar sin afectar la solucion

Comment: Estoy postulando esta pregunta para reapertura. No sé la respuesta, pero leyendo brevemente [Does the MixColumns step come before or after AddRoundKey in AES decryption?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/2711) entiendo que no es necesario incluir más detalles, podría tener respuesta, no es demasiado amplia, ni requiere una respuesta extensa.

Comment: Pienso lo mismo que @Mariano. Aunque la pregunta sea corta se puede responder sin problema.

Answer (score 1):

Si ves el pseudo código del AES ( puedes tener toda la descripción aqui en la https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard )
verás que addroundkey esta usado 3 veces mientras el mixcolumns solo una vez en las rondas

Por la naturaleza de las operaciones matemáticas, si inviertes las dos operaciones (siendo respectivamente una multiplicación y una suma de los polinomios), es resultado será diferente ya que no son operaciones linealmente intercambiables. Se puede eventualmente intercambiar pero en este caso tendrías que usar un polinomio adaptado. (y más operaciones matemáticas, no se recomendaria)